# Constructor call with varibales without quoting the explicit classtype in Java?

Tags: java, variables, constructor, call

is there any possibility to instance a class with a variable and without explicit calling the classtype of the object?

For example we have a class cat and a string which represents the String cat. Is it possible to call the class cat like below or similar in the code?

```
public class MyMainClass {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     String name="cat";

     //normal methode of instancing the class Cat:
     Cat cat=new Cat();

     //my method
     name cat=new name(); // because name="cat" this should be Cat cat=new Cat(); 

     }
}


class Cat{
// whatsoever
}
```

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: `String name=new String("cat");` is a waste. Just do `String name="cat"`

Comment: There are some things can be done along these lines using reflection or generics, I'd need more detail on what and why you are trying to do before I could make any recommendations though.

Comment: I think that you're got yourself a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use reflection:**

```
String nameString = "com.example.Test";
Class name = Class.forName(nameString);
Object instance = name.newInstance();
Test test; // Defined if is instanceof Test

if(instance instanceof Test) {
    // Yeah! now you can do this: test = (Test)instance; and something else...
}
```

***Note: You MUST enter the entire package name in the string.***

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection:

```
String name = "com.foo.Cat"; // Note fully qualified name
Object object = Class.forName(name).newInstance();
```

but you won't know what type you have, unless you use `instanceof`.

And the value of `name` can't be used to create a variable of that name.